Which airplanes designed for Earth could also fly on Mars?
According to,
Records in Flight: Altitude

For years, the unofficial record was held by Joseph A. Walker, who
reached 354,199ft in a North American X-15 in 1963.
When you consider that the highest altitudes flown by corporate jets
today is 51,000 ft, and Concorde achieved the highest airliner
altitude at 60,000 ft, that’s impressive!

According to,
air density of earth at 100 kms

At a height of 50 km, the air density is about 0.0001% of the density
at sea level.

And according to,
Air density of Mars

The atmosphere of Mars is much thinner and colder than Earth's having
a max density 20g/m3 (about 2% of Earth's value)

Considering 2% is much more than 0.0001%, does that mean experimental aircrafts like the X-15 would fly on Mars? Or are other factors to take in consideration?
Which made for Earth airplanes would fly on Mars?

Walker rode a rocket plane on a ballistic trajectory into space - he went really fast in the atmosphere, pointed up, and let his own inertia do the work. That's not really evidence that the X-15 can "fly" at an altitude with no atmosphere - you probably wouldn't say a rock thrown out the window of an airplane was "flying". The X-15 is more like a missile than an aircraft at high altitudes, since it doesn't actually use aerodynamic lift or control surfaces.

if you mean sustained flight, I was checking some other figures, apparently record is 30 kms where air density is 18 g/ m3

@NuclearHoagie btw, the answer can be "none" if it's the true one

apparently you would need to reach an altitude of 45 kms to have an air density similar to Mars . Being able to fly with an air density of 18 g / m3 doesnt seem that far of 2 g / m3, considering at sea level is 1225 g / m3 . May be it's even technically possible?

Ingenuity taught us that powered flight on Mars is technically possible. To lift Ginny, it had to spin its rotors at about 2,400 rpm. I found an article that claimed that a Robinson copter can spin at 3,000, but we have to account for the fact that Ingenuity weighed less than 5 pounds, and any would-be aircraft heavier than that would have to spin even faster. So, no, not really.

@NuclearHoagie - X-15 flew two types of mission profiles, high altitude and high speed. Although even the flights that remained within the atmosphere likely had a ballistic component that helped keep them climbing after engine burnout. It would be interesting to know what the highest altitude the X-15 could have flown in level flight, if we ignore the fuel needed to get to that altitude since the X-15 engine didn't burn for very long.

Pablo - 45 km is likely an average between the plains and Olympus Mons. For "sea level" on Mars it's more like 30 km or about 100,000 ft. Of course you would need to fly low  using terrain following radar like the B-1 so that you can stay as much in the "thick" part of the atmosphere, as you can, otherwise it would probably be pretty easy to get into a coffin corner situation. And I shudder to think what takeoff and landing would be like.

According to the author of X-Plane, it is possible but not with an ordinary plane.

An aircraft is anything that flies by using the atmosphere for support, including gliders, powered airplanes, helicopters and balloons. Are you asking about aircraft or airplanes?

Apart from the low air density problem, Mars air is 95% CO2. But an engine needs oxygen to burn its fuel. So a Mars plane would need to carry its own oxidizer, although a Mars jet could still use the air as reaction mass.

@StevePemberton (et al.) related to the ballistic flights: How did the X-15 control attitude above the Kármán line? and What would a "Kármán plane" look like, a bird, or a plane? and Is it 100x more work to fly on Mars? also related: Could a helicopter fly on Mars?

@gdd I'm asking about airplanes

"In 2001, the NASA Helios achieved the joint world records of highest altitude attained by an electrically powered aircraft and the highest altitude in horizontal flight by a winged aircraft, when it was flown at 96,863 ft." <--- that might work?

I was wondering if when they go to Mars they could take some airplanes made here , assuming they have a spaceship big enough to carry them, and they would work

Apparently I got it wrong, Mars air density is 20g/m3  not 2g/m3, that would make the air density of those sustained flight airplanes which travels at 30 kms the same than Mars

"But it’s Russian pilot Alexandr Fedotov who holds the world altitude record, set on August 31, 1977, when his MiG E-266M reached a mere 123,523 feet. " (37kms) <--

@uhoh, ok, done !

Pablo - The 123,000 ft flight had a large ballistic component to it, similar to the X-15 flights, although maybe not to the same degree. 123,000 ft was essentially the apogee of the ballistic trajectory. From Wikipedia: ”On 31 August 1977, Ye-266M again flown by Fedotov, set the recognized absolute altitude record for a jet aircraft under its own power. He reached 37,650 meters (123,520 ft) in zoom climb (the absolute altitude record is different from the record for sustained altitude in horizontal flight). The aircraft was a MiG-25RB re-engined with the powerful R-15BF2-300.”

Helios is a good example; as it is, it would fly "fast" at mars ground level. yet it weighs 2/3 less on mars, and could be built either less massive, or with greater wingspan and area for same mass
